# Ordering inside of pipeline

Tags: r

Is there is some way to include the ordering part inside of the pipe without having to make 2 separate variables.

```
# Find average tooth length by suppliment, by dose, rounded to 1 decimal point #
tooth_df <- ToothGrowth %>% 
  group_by(supp, dose) %>% 
  summarize(mean(len, na.rm = T), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(
    avglength = round(tooth_df$`mean(len, na.rm = T)`, digits = 1)
  )

tooth_df1 <- tooth_df[order(tooth_df$supp, -tooth_df$dose),]
```

Comment: @user438383 Actually, OP did mean *pipeline*, not pipe. The code they posted uses a pattern generally called “pipeline”. It *uses* the pipe operator.

Comment: You are looking for `arrange`, i.e. try `... %>% summarize( avglength = round(mean(len, na.rm = TRUE), digits = 1), .groups = "drop") %>% arrange(supp, desc(dose))`.

Comment: You appear to be conflating two flavors of R: tidyverse and base. Your ordering attempt is base R while tidyverse has a tidy method: `arrange`. Consider picking one flavor for consistency. Happy coding!

Comment: @Parfait yes, just saw another reply recommending arrange which did indeed work, I will also try to make sure to stay consistent from now on, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can include the ordering part inside the pipe using the arrange() function from the dplyr package. Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)

tooth_df <- ToothGrowth %>% 
  group_by(supp, dose) %>% 
  summarize(mean(len, na.rm = T), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(avglength = round(`mean(len, na.rm = T)`, digits = 1)) %>% 
  arrange(supp, desc(dose))
```

In this code, the arrange() function is used to order the tooth_df data frame by the supp column in ascending order and the dose column in descending order. The desc() function is used to indicate that the dose column should be sorted in descending order.

Also, note that the mutate() function uses backticks to reference the newly created mean(len, na.rm = T) column within the same pipeline without needing to refer to the data frame name tooth_df.

Comment: thank you so much, I had seen that the arrange function was an option but was never able to get it to work. And thank you for the info about mutate, I am so used to adding the table name before columns from working with SQL it was a second-nature habit that I will try to break. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I would be grateful if you mark this question as solved. :) Happy coding!